# How to iterate two lists in Java Simultaneously?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to Iterate two **ArrayLists** to call a fucntion called **findProfit(ele,c)** but I'm getting confused to getting right way to do it. Please provide all possible solution of the code.

```
public void calProfitIndex(ArrayList<ArrayList<Package>> elemetList,ArrayList<Integer> capacity){
    ....ArrayList<Package> ele: elemetList && Integer c: capacity...{

                findProfit(ele,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: loop inside a loop

Comment: "**Gimme teh codez**" questions are unwanted on SO

Comment: I need to Iterate both simultaneously

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by List Iterator

```
public void calProfitIndex(ArrayList<ArrayList<Package>> elemetList,ArrayList<Integer> capacity){
        Iterator elemetListIterator=elemetList.iterator();
        Iterator capacityIterator=capacity.iterator();
        while(elemetListIterator.hasNext() && capacityIterator.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList<Package> elemet=(ArrayList<Package>) elemetListIterator.next();
            Integer cap=(Integer) capacityIterator.next();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That you want to iterate two lists simultaneously would tend to suggest that you should have had **one** list of composite objects, each containing a `Package` reference and an integer capacity.  (End of lecture).

But you do have a few options if you want to iterate two lists simultaneously:

1) use explicit `Iterator`s for both lists:

```
Iterator<Package> pIter = elementList.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> cIter = capacity.iterator();
while (pIter.hasNext() && cIter.hasNext()) {
    Package p = pIter.next();
    Integer c = cIter.next();
        ...
}
if (pIter.hasNext()) 
    System.err.println("Too few capacity items");
if (cIter.hasNext())
    System.err.println("Too few Package items");
```

2) use an index counter:

```
if (elementList.size() != capacity.size())
    System.err.println("Lists aren't the same size");
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size(); ++i){
        Package p = elementList.get(i);
        Integer c = capacity.get(i);
        ....
    }
}
```

3) Use the enhanced `for` for one list and an `Iterator` for the other:

```
Iterator<Integer> cIter = capacity.iterator();
for (Package p : elementList){
   if (!cIter.hasNext()) {
       System.err.println("Too few capacity items");
       break;
   }
   Integer c = cIter.next();
    ....
}
if (cIter.hasNext())
    System.err.println("Too few Package items");
```